# material-ui@next Drawer classes overrides aren't working

Tags: css, material-ui

I have a drawer that I am trying to override the CSS for `paperAnchorLeft`. I am using `injectSheet` because I need to calculate some of the CSS values based on the component properties. This has been working perfectly until I upgraded to the latest beta (beta 21) today from beta 18 that we were previously on. Now, the injected style is a lower priority than the `.MUIDrawer-paperAnchorLeft-#` class so none of my overrides are taking effect.

Is there something in the latest beta that changed that I am missing? If I use `!important` on everything in my override it works, but that feels real hacky so I'd rather get it back to working properly.

Styles:

```
const drawerStyles = (theme) => ({ 
  anchorLeft: { 
    left: (props) => { 
        if(props.navigationBarExpanded) { 
            return theme.navBar.expandedWidth;
        }
        return theme.navBar.width;
    },
  },
});
```

Render function:

```
render = () => ({ 

  <Drawer anchor="left" open={this.props.drawer.open} type="persistent"
            classes={{paperAnchorLeft: this.props.classes.anchorLeft}}
  >
    {content}
  </Drawer>
});
```

Inject Sheets

```
export default LeftDrawer = injectSheet(drawerStyles)(LeftDrawer);
```

Comment: are you seeing any errors in the console ?

Comment: No, nothing in the console.